# Is it possible to get all comments of Post from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook Api https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
Currently i am able to get only own comments, i can not see other people comments on my post.I have allowed all permissions, see attached

[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTVRg.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following syntax of Facebook Graph API:

```
GET /{object-id}/comments
```

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/comments
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4p4e8g

Comment: Yes i can only see my own comments on post but not other peoples comments on my post.